# Autoencoder: Layer "model_3" expects 1 input(s), but it received 64 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I have two batches of length 64. Each index is an ndarray of size size (128, 128, 3).

My Code:

```
ae_encoder = Conv2D(32, (2,2), padding='same')(input)
ae_encoder = LeakyReLU()(ae_encoder)
ae_encoder = Flatten()(ae_encoder)
ae_encoder_output = Dense(Z_DIM, activation='relu')(ae_encoder)
```

I can't seem to find why it is treating the entire batch of size 64) as different channels. Shouldn't it is supposed to be iterating over the ndarray inside these batches?

Error:

```
ValueError: Layer "model_3" expects 1 input(s), but it received 64 input tensors.
```

**Update-1**
x_train and y_train are both lists of length 64 and each index is of shape (128, 128, 3).

[image: Shape]

Sample input (Input is quite large so can't copy it entirely)
[image: Data]

Comment: Show your entire model and provide dummy data.

Comment: @AloneTogether I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to implement a vanilla Autoencoder, where the input shape should equals the output shape then you have to change the last decoder layer to this:

```py
ae_decoder_output = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same',strides=(1,1))(ae_decoder)
```

resulting in the output shape `(None, 128, 128, 3)`. Also, you need to make sure that your data has the shape `(samples, 128, 128, 3)`.